# Magento 2.2.6 : Authorize.net not working. Giving Below Error

Tags: checkout, sales-order, magento2.2.6

> **Argument 1 passed to Magento\Authorizenet\Model\Directpost\Request::__construct() must be
>   an instance of Magento\Framework\Intl\DateTimeFactory**

This error is getting displayed when I am clicking on the place order button in Magento2.

Comment: share the code of constructor for this file : Magento\Authorizenet\Model\Directpost\Request.php

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem which happened after Auth.net phased out MD5 based transHash in favor of SHA-512. To fix, I replaced these two files -

```
/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php
/public_html/vendor/magento/module-authorizenet/Model/Directpost/Request.php
```

with the following files

```
https://gist.github.com/onamfc/6bcd020c113de1a8f68d78eac17fea7b
https://gist.github.com/onamfc/9bd3b556fd85fc4f9a9d7c47b4f195b1
```